# How do I Create a CloudWatch Email Alert With Custom Content?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to edit an AWS CloudWatch alert that sends an email to my team such that custom content is sent in the email. Currently, all email alerts contain only auto-generated content. The email content contains the reason for the alert, a link to the alarm in the AWS console, and sections for Alarm Details, Threshold, and Monitored Metric. However, I want to add custom content listing likely causes of the alert and procedures to execute when receiving the alert. Does anybody know how custom content can be added to a CloudWatch alert email?

I have read existing AWS CloudWatch Alarm documentation such as [How to Create/Edit a CloudWatch Alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ConsoleAlarms.html), and [How to create a CPU Usage Alarm that Sends an Email](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html). I have also tried various Google searches and searches for existing questions here on SO but to no avail. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a Lambda trigger to the alarm and send an email using AWS SES SMTP credentials, creating a formatted email content with alarm trigger event data.

Answer (score -1):

You can flow the document you mentioned above: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_AlarmAtThresholdEC2.html

Choose existing SNS topic or create new one, after that enter slack email and when have any alarms will be sent to Slack channel that was integrated Email app by you

[image]

**`xxxxxxxxxx@x.slack.com`** you can use add [Email](https://slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email) App in Slack like icon below

[image]